# Force create existing folder with Meteor

Tags: meteor

When I use the command:

```
meteor create myfolder
```

It won't by default allow meteor to install itself if the folder is already existing. I can't find an option to force it. Is it really necessary that Meteor creates the directory by itself first or is this just because of 'good practice'?

I want to automate the creation of a folder first and run the meteor command *afterwards*, hence the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want a shell script like the following:

```
$DIR = <some variable>

if [ ! -f "$DIR" ]; then
    meteor create tempDir
    mv tempDir/* "$DIR/"
    rmdir tempDir
fi
```

which will copy the contents into your new directory, as long as it doesn't contain any Meteor files already.

Comment: That's what I am currently doing now - or actually more similar than have a 'pre-created directory. Nicer would be if there was a '--force' option somehow.

Comment: There is no option to overwrite an existing directory. There are some requests already issued: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/2276